# How to embed a function supplied by a extension into a .ods file

Tags: file-transfer, libreoffice, libreoffice-calc

I am using a function for sorting arrays inside my calc document, which is supplied via an [extension](https://forum.openoffice.org/en/forum/viewtopic.php?f=21&t=56916). However, transferring the file to a different system, where the extension isn't installed, breaks the function. Since the file is designed to be shared with many other users, it is impractical to instruct each of them to install the necessary extension individually.

Is there a way to embed/link the function supplied by the extensions to the .ods-file itself in such a way that the function wont break on file transfer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I tried to embed an add-in into a document by modifying manifest.xml, the add-in was ignored.  Also, I ran into other limitations of embedding, such as not allowing importing from a pythonpath folder.

The documentation is rather difficult, but these two links perhaps support my conclusion:

- https://wiki.openoffice.org/wiki/Documentation/DevGuide/Spreadsheets/Spreadsheet_Add-Ins
- https://wiki.openoffice.org/wiki/Documentation/DevGuide/WritingUNO/Deployment_Options_for_Components

So it looks like the possibilities are to either require people to install the extension, or use a [user-defined function](https://help.libreoffice.org/Calc/User-Defined_Functions) instead of an add-in.  It should be possible to embed a UDF in a document.